# Remove the naming convention rule for finding ViewComponents

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-view-component-class) the following rules determine whether a class is a ViewComponent:

1. Deriving from ViewComponent
2. Decorating a class with the [ViewComponent] attribute, or deriving from a class with the [ViewComponent] attribute
3. Creating a class where the name ends with the suffix ViewComponent

I am adding View components to an existing project, and in this project there are classes that are Suffixed "viewComponent" e.g. `ReviewComponent`.

When I call `IViewComponentSelector.SelectComponent` an exception is being thrown because the runtime cannot find an InvokeAsync method on these classes.

So my question is, is it possible to disable or remove rule #3 so that my existing classes aren't mistaken for View components, or is there a way to flag these classes as "not view components"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`NonViewComponent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.nonviewcomponentattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) attribute on the classes in question, if that's a workable solution for you:

```cs
[NonViewComponent]
public class ReviewComponent
{
    // ...
```